Navigating My Farewell: Insights for Managing My Exit
I’ve been with my company for several years and recently resigned.  Over the past year, I’ve felt demotivated, especially after being passed over for a promotion.
Now, my final digital meeting is approaching. My boss has ignored me since I resigned and likely won’t acknowledge my departure, though he did for others. It feels awkward to bring up my departure, but if I don’t, it might be strange since some know I’m leaving. Others got supportive reactions when they mentioned leaving, but I’m unsure if I’ll receive the same.
Should I join the meeting? If so, what should I say? Or should I skip it?

What are you hoping to accomplish? What is the outcome you want? Take the [tour] to find out more about how to ask useful, answerable questions here.

I want to conclude my employment relationship professionally, but I'm feeling uncertain about how to go about it. I would appreciate specific guidance on the best way to handle this situation effectively.

Since you're technically on the company's payroll still, you might want to join the meeting if it's not optional. I would just simply mind my own business on the call though. You don't have to force yourself to talk. Just attend, listen and be done with it.

VTC - this is fundamentally a question about a specific choice: Should I go to the meeting or not. Which we cannot help with. However, there are elements of this question that could be a good question around exit interviews - I would suggest re-wording it and looking at our rules for questions and then going from there.

I'd say as little as possible.

@JosephDoggie why?

Is this your first job?

@Sun: You're overthinking this, which is common for first-time job leavers.

@DanielR.Collins So what would you do?

@Sun: See my answer below.

" Additionally, I worry that my boss might speak negatively about me if I'm not there." If that's his intention, then what's stopping him from doing so after you have left? If your sole reason for attending is to censor people from speaking (even if it would be wrong to say those things), that's not really a meaningful attendance.

@Sun the updside of saying things is very little.  There are only a handful of people from past jobs I've kept in contact with, and I really don't see ANY of them anymore.  The potential downside of saying the wrong thing is great.

Nothing hard is happening. You don't sue each other, you don't report each other for criminal offenses, you did not fake stories about each other. You goal should be to let the best traces in them. This "feeling demotivated" looks to me like a nice-talk, I can not decode its real meaning, it could help. Boss is also probably ignoring you because at the moment that you go, you became unimportant. Guys are coming, partially into your place, are more important. These are nothing. There are decades to come and you do not know, how you will ever meet them. Let it on good terms as possible!

Let it go. Move on. Focus on the new job and don't waste energy worrying about the old one.
How your departure is communicated to the rest of the company is your manager's decisions. If they decide to keep it on the down low, that's their choice.
Once you have resigned, you should still do your job as assigned until the last day. If you are expected to be at the meeting, you should show up, regardless whether it makes sense or not.
On your last day you can reach out to anyone who you feel a connection to and say your good byes privately.

Just do your job as usual, attend the meeting as usual, and don't make a big deal about it one way or the other. Frankly, it doesn't matter.
OP clarifies in comments that they're leaving their first job. It's common for first-time-job leavers to have a lot of their personal identity wrapped up in the first job, and undergo an unreasonable amount of anxiety, grief, and desire to "make a statement". Don't. The business would fire you at the drop of a hat if it made a dollar more income. You will have many other jobs, and the business will have many other employees.
If you feel that the business has treated you unfairly, then screw 'em. They don't get an erg more of your life-energy or mental-state.
For context, see also numerous other questions posed by overly anxious first-time-job leavers:

What should I do if I am strongly burned out at work, but resigning now would cause problems for my coworkers and burn bridges?
How much should I care about the quality of projects that aren't mine?
Dilemma about staying or leaving my current position
Stuck at a top company that discriminates arbitrarily

See this related Q&A for suggestion of a brief goodbye email if desired:

I've been asked to resign and leave, what to do and how do I tell my team?

